# Не передаются данные из функции python

Tags: python

Что то я понять не могу, почему такой вариант кода не работает. Я же в функции execute_db() вызываю connect_db(), почему переменные в таком случае не передаются?

```
import mysql.connector

def connect_db():
    connect = mysql.connector.connect(host='IP', user='USER', password='PASS', database='DB')
    cursor = connect.cursor()


def execute_db(query):
    connect_db()
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connect.close()
    
    return data


data = execute_db("SELECT * FROM logs")
print(data)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Timur\Desktop\Григорий\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = execute_db("SELECT * FROM logs")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Timur\Desktop\Григорий\test.py", line 10, in execute_db
    cursor.execute(query)
    ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

MysqlConnect.py

```
import mysql.connector


class MysqlConnect(object):
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port=3306) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.database = database
        self.port = port


    def connect_db(self) -> None:
        self.connect = mysql.connector.connect(host = self.host, user = self.user, password = self.password, database = self.database, port = self.port)
        self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()


    def execute_db(self, query) -> dict:
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.connect.close()
        
        return self.data
```

main.py

```
import MysqlConnect


connect = MysqlConnect.MysqlConnect(host='', user='', password='', database='')

data = connect.execute_db('SELECT * FROM logs')

print(data)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\py\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = connect.execute_db('SELECT * FROM logs')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\py\MysqlConnect.py", line 19, in execute_db
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MysqlConnect' object has no attribute 'cursor'
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\py>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае нужно возвращать переменные из функции и принимать их в вызывающей функции:

```py
def connect_db():
    ...
    return connect, cursor

def execute_db(query):
    connect, cursor = connect_db()
    ...
```

Если вам эта переменная нужна будет потом ещё где-то, то лучше сделать класс, в который поместить эти функции и хранить значение этой переменной в поле (экземпляра) класса.

Суть в том, что переменные внутри функции локальные. Вернее, в питоне всё сложнее. В функции можете читать глобальные переменные, но не можете их писать без явного указания, что они `global`. Но лучше на глобальные переменные и не завязываться. Хорошая функция - "чистая" функция. Т.е. та, которая получает все аргументы в явном виде и отдаёт результаты тоже в явном виде через `return`.

Comment: Я там дополнил описание. Чтоб передать две переменные я так должен делать?

Comment: @АгрегатАгрегатович Это делается ещё проще, я поменял ответ. Забыл, что у вас две переменных

Comment: оо, благодарю. Не знал)

Comment: @АгрегатАгрегатович На самом деле из функции возвращается кортеж, а там где она вызывается, происходит распаковка кортежа. Распаковка-упаковка аргументов - очень полезные вещи в питоне, много где используются.

Comment: еще раз обновил, но уже с классом. Можете посказать как правильено обратиться к аттрибуту другого метода)

Comment: @АгрегатАгрегатович А что, не работает? С виду всё правильно, только `self.query` и `self.data` не нужны, для `data` используйте обычную переменную, а `self.query` просто нет смысла сохранять.

Comment: добавил ошибку которую выдает

Comment: @АгрегатАгрегатович А, так нужно `connect_db` где-то вызвать. Можно и в `init` в конце `self.connect_db()`. А можно снаружи в `main`: `connect.connect_db()`.

Comment: я пробовал и в инити и в самом connect_db(), так еще больше ошибок сыпится)

Comment: У меня задача чтоб в main.py работать только с execute_db(), а connect_db() использовать только внутри класса, я просто сам коннект к базе и запрос к базе разделил, не знаю пока зачем но разделил)

Comment: Ну тогда `self.connect_db()` в конце `__init__` должен работать по идее.

Comment: даа, все работает. У меня на компьютере был установлен mysql-connector а должен быть установлен mysql-connector-python